# Можно ли в STL Filesystem под Linux сравнить разделы для двух fs::path?

Tags: c++, файловая-система, stl

В общем, для Windows вроде как всё очевидно (т.к. раздел == диск):

```
if (source.root_name() == destination.root_name())
{
    /* переименование */
}
else
{
    /* копирование с удалением */
}
```

А вот для Linux не могу найти хоть что-то. Видимо никак?

Comment: А почему просто не использовать `rename`? Ведь эта функция, как раз таки, перемещает или, если возможно, переименовывает файл или папку. Тобишь вы пытаетесь сделать то, что и так реализовано

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, и правда, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, примерно так?

```
if (rename (old, new)) {
  if (errno == EXDEV) {
    /* копирование с удалением */
  } else {
    /* ошибка */
  }
}
```

Comment: А, да, вопрос был про STL...